# How do I make the apache2 service to run automatically on container restart?

Tags: docker, dockerfile, containers, apache2

I have this ubuntu docker container with apache2 installed in it and I have a webpage hosted in it.
I basically want the apache2 service to run automatically everytime I run the container.
I dont want to go inside the container everytime and start the service.

I have tried building an image with Dockerfile that does the job.

```
FROM apache
ADD ./index.html /var/www/html
ENTRYPOINT apachectl -D FOREGROUND
```

But is there a way to do it without having to build the image with dockerfile and use ENTRYPOINT command?

Answer (score 1):

The base image you have added in Dockerfile is not exist at all it should be `from https:2.4`.

**What is httpd?**

> The **Apache HTTP Server**, colloquially called Apache, is a Web server application notable for playing a key role in the initial growth of the World Wide Web. Originally based on the NCSA HTTPd server, development of Apache began in early 1995 after work on the NCSA code stalled. Apache quickly overtook NCSA HTTPd as the dominant HTTP server, and has remained the most popular HTTP server in use since April 1996.

[docker-hub-httpd](https://hub.docker.com/_/httpd)

Now come to your problem, you do not need to define `ENTRYPOINT` or `CMD` at all, as it already from base image.

```
FROM httpd:2.4
COPY ./index.html /usr/local/apache2/htdocs/
```

that's it, do not overide `CMD` it will restart when container restarted or docker service.